# How to select adjacent fields with same values in two-dimentional array

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've got a two-dimmentional array filled with some data. I want to select all the fields with the same value as field [0][0] that are connected to it in a way presented on the image below:

[image: highlighted fields]

*Example of matrix with fields I want to select highlighted in green (selected fields are adjacent to each other by at least one of four sides (N,W,S,E):*

Can you think of some easy algorythm that will achieve that? I don't hope for some ready to use code - more like some guidelines.

Comment: [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive algorithm. Check each of the adjacent cells, and if it matches recurse with that cell being the starting point. Collect all the matching cells in a list. To avoid infinite loops, check whether the cell is already in the result list before recursing.

Comment: 'To avoid infinite loops, check whether the cell is already in the result list before recursing' will need a visited so do not go there again list too?

Comment: @tgkprog Every place that's visited is in the result list.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, something like this maybe...?

Set `match` equal to the content of (0,0).
Create a list `open` and a list `closed`.
Push (0,0) on to `open`.

While `open` contains elements: { pop an element off `open` and push it to `closed`. Look at all adjacent slots to that element in the matrix and for each adjacent slot whose contents equals `match`: { take the coordinates of that slot and if the coordinates are not in `closed` or `open`, then push them to `open`. } }

Once done, `closed` should contain the desired list of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your hints I came up with this solution:

```
   function findAdjacent(matrix){
        var x= 0,y=0; //starting point
        return check(x,y,matrix);
    }

    function check(x,y,matrix){//where the recursive magic happens
        if(matrix[x][y]==1){
            checked[x][y]="1";
            if(x-1>=0 && matrix[x-1][y]==1 && checked[x-1][y]!=1){
                check(x-1,y,matrix);
            }
            if( y-1>=0 && matrix[x][y-1]==1 && checked[x][y-1]!=1){
                check(x,y-1,matrix);
            }
            if(x+1<matrix.length && matrix[x+1][y]==1 && checked[x+1][y]!=1){
                check(x+1,y,matrix);
            }
            if(y+1<matrix.length && matrix[x][y+1]==1 && checked[x][y+1]!=1){
                check(x,y+1,matrix);
            }
        }
        return checked;
    }

    var startingMatrix = [];
    startingMatrix[0] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1];
    startingMatrix[1] = [1,1,3,4,1,6,1,1];
    startingMatrix[2] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,7,1];
    startingMatrix[3] = [5,1,1,1,5,1,7,1];
    startingMatrix[4] = [5,2,3,4,1,1,7,1];
    startingMatrix[5] = [1,2,1,4,5,1,1,1];
    startingMatrix[6] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1];
    startingMatrix[7] = [1,1,3,4,4,1,3,1];

    var checked=[]; //empty matrix for marking up checked files
    checked[0] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[1] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[2] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[3] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[4] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[5] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[6] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    checked[7] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    (function() {
        document.write("<br>");
        findAdjacent(startingMatrix);

    })();
```

It seems to be working just fine. But surely there is some way to improve this code, right?